# How to make a div to be displayed even after refreshing the web page or reopening the browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually I am making a web page using **HTML,CSS and Javascript** in which there is only one html page with functions like **when a person clicks on a particular button, that the **current div** will not be displayed but the another div will be displayed.** At last there will be a home div which will act like the home page of the website.
**I want to make that home page to be displayed once a person fills all the credentials and always only the home page should be displayed even after reloading that web page or reopening the web page.**
I have researched everywhere but couldn't find the exact solution of the code.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try with LocalStorege, hold information, and check if the condition is true, if it is just immediately execute the logic.
This should solve the problem for you.

Comment: I would suggest cookies and JavaScript. They have some disadvantages (send over internet, require web server, etc.) over the local storage, but cookies might be initially simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-uawtkc

Tried to simulate the problem and solve it